# Ensure sharing rules from the calling class are enforced for the the 'UtilityClass' Apex class

Tags: trailhead, winter19

Getting below error while attempting Winter 19- Platform Developer Maintenance exam Hands on Challenge.

> Ensure sharing rules from the calling class are enforced for the the 'UtilityClass' Apex class.

Class code is same as given in this trailhead module : 
[Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform-developer-i-certification-maintenance-winter-19/work-with-the-lightning-map-component-and-apex-inherited-sharing)

Modified below classes as asked in the above mentioned Hands on challenge
UtilityClass:

```
public Inherited Sharing class UtilityClass {
   ...
}
```

TowerMapControllerClass : (Tried With Sharing/Inherited Sharing/Nothing for this class)

```
public With Sharing class TowerMapControllerClass {..}
```

Comment: If I follow the trailhead module, your `UtilityClass` is not same as mentioned in the trailhead, there's no `inherited sharing` clause in there.

Comment: @JayantDas It is not in the provided code no, but if you scroll down the first step of the challenge is "Copy the helper class code block, UtilityClass, from above and modify it so the sharing rules are enforced based on the sharing setting of the calling class." which means he should add Inherit sharing to that class. In theory his code should be working. My only advice is to check the API version of your code.

Comment: @gNerb I see, I already had completed the challenge so was not able to see that part.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced '**I**nherited **S**haring' with '**i**nherited **s**haring' then trail-head passed the challenge.

Though apex is case insensitive, syntactically my code is correct and class is saved. Trail-head validation check for case sensitive match.

Its an issue with trail-head challenge validation.